# Publish page using PnP.Powershell

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm editing some publishing pages in bulk using PnP.Powershell. How can I republish the pages after changeing them?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample script to publish page:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "<SiteURL>"

$pageslib = Get-PnPList -Identity "Site Pages"
$pages = Get-PnPListItem -List $pageslib
foreach($page in $pages){
    $page.File.Publish("Published")
}

Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Reference: [How to publish all pages in SitePages library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint-developer/how-to-publish-all-pages-in-sitepages-library/m-p/251117)

And another one using `PageRelativeURL`: [Publish Page in SharePoint using PowerShell.](https://www.codesharepoint.com/powershell/publish-page-in-sharepoint-using-powershell)